# Shoe the image URL on Update page of the Crud

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

> this is a template page of a Edit Page of crud, when we render this edit page all fields which are already uploaded will be shown except the image, how can we see the already uploaded image in image field, hope you guys got that.

```
<body>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h1 class="text-center alert alert-info">Modify Order Details</h1>
            <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="category">Select a Category :- </label>
                    <select name="category" id="category">
                    <option value="None"selected >None</option>  
                    <option value="Tshirt" {% if products.category == 'Tshirt' %} selected {% endif %}>Tshirt</option>
                    <option value="Jeans" {% if products.category == 'Jeans' %} selected {% endif %}>Jeans</option>
                    <option value="Jacket" {% if products.category == 'Jacket' %} selected {% endif %}>Jacket</option>
                    <option value="Shoes" {% if products.category == 'Shoes' %} selected {% endif %} >Shoes</option>
                    <option value="Watch" {% if products.category == 'Watch' %} selected {% endif %} >Watch</option>
                    </select>   <br><br>
                    
                    <label for="product_name">Select a Product: </label>
                    <select name="product_name" id="product_name" value="{{products.product_name}}" >
                    <option value="{{products.product_name}}" selected readonly >{{products.product_name}}</option> 
                    
                    </select><br><br><br>


                <label for="product_price">Product Price:</label>
                <input type="text" id="product_price" class="form-control" name="product_price" value="{{products.product_price}}" pattern="^[^ ].+[^ ]$" title="Please Remove Extra Spaces" required><br>

                <label for="supplier_images">Image:</label>
                <input type="file" name="image"></a> <br><br>
                <!-- <span>Current image:</span> <img src="{{products.image.url}}" alt="" width="40"> -->
                <br><br>

                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success">
            </form>
        </div>

    </div><br><br>
    <h3><a href="{% url 'supplier_dashboard' %}">Back</a></h3>
```

Comment: You have this line in your code which shows the image already stored (if uncommented): `<!-- <span>Current image:</span> <img src="{{products.image.url}}" alt="" width="40"> -->` so I am guessing you are asking something not clear in your question...are you asking how to show an image that isn't previously stored, or what?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using a django template  to display an uploaded image, you cuold do something like this:

```
{% if products.image.url %}
   <span>Current image:</span> <img src="{{products.image.url}}" alt="Current Image" width="100">
{% endif %}
```